# PhpMailer Multiple Attachments

Tags: php, phpmailer

I´m trying to send multiple attachments with phpmailer. I get the whole url of the files I'm trying to send and with a `for loop` I put it into the `$mail->addAttachment` parameter, but when i try to send it throws the error:

> Could not access file:....

```
 // ADJUNTOS
 $urls_x = explode(',',$urls);

 // QUITA EL ULTIMO ELEMENTO DE LA LISTA QUE VIENE VACIO
 $unset = count($urls_x);
 unset($urls_x[$unset-1]);
 $urls_count = count($urls_x);

 $nombre = $paciente['nombre1'].' '.$paciente['nombre2'].' 
 '.$paciente['apellido1'].' '.$paciente['apellido2'];
 $correo = strtolower($paciente['email']);

 $mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
 try {
      $mail->CharSet="utf-8";
      $mail->setFrom('sender_x@xxxx.com.co', 'SENDER');
      $mail->addAddress($correo, $nombre);
      $mail->Subject = 'XXXX SUBJECT';
      $mail->IsHTML(true);
      $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../../img/mail/body.png', 'bodyimg',  
      '../../img/mail/body.png');
      $mail->Body = "<img src=\"cid:bodyimg\" />";

      for($i=0;$i<$urls_count;$i++){
     $mail->addAttachment($urls_x[$i]);
      }
 }
```

Thanks a lot for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in URLs instead of local paths, which is deliberately **not supported** by `addAttachment`. PHPMailer is not an HTTP client, so fetch the files yourself, and then pass them to PHPMailer. For example:

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/file.jpg', file_get_contents($url));
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/file.jpg');
```

Alternatively, skip writing it to a file and pass it as a string (make sure you pass in a filename or set the MIME type - [see PHPMailer docs on that](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment)):

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$mail->addStringAttachment($data, 'file.jpg');
```

You might want to do some error checking around these too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();          
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'jswan';
$mail->Password = 'secret';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name                               
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo 'Message has been sent';
```

try this, its working for me. you can add multiple add attachment to send attachments

Comment: He's already doing that. - there's a loop around the call to `addAttachment`.